# XML to json with transform

Tags: json, xml, go

I have the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2016-09-14T13:58:30Z</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:decimal">1.2</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

And I am unmarshaling it to the following structs:

```
type Value struct {
    Data []Data `xml:"anyType"`
}

type Data struct {
    Key string `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

I would ultimately like to marshal them to json of this structure:

```
{
   timestamp: [the value of xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"]
   value: [the value of xsi:type="xsd:decimal"]
}
```

I'm new to Go, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Field tags in Go allow specifying any number of distinct values — separated by spaces.
So in your simple case just add `json:"value"` after `xml:"..."` and then marshal
the unmarshaled value to JSON.

Note that I mean spaces inside a single tag, not a space-separated tags:

```
Field string `xml:"myns Xyzzy" json:"Blorb"`
```

In more complex cases it might be needed to have distinct types for unmarshaling
and marshaling, and shovel data with required intermediate conversions
between the values of these types.